# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at deprem.js:11

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch data from an earthquake API and i am getting this error. I've tried to fix it but i am very new to js, so i'm open for any kinda help.. Here is the entire code(deprem.js) :

```
const depremAra = document.querySelector('button');

depremAra.addEventListener('click',() => {
    fetch('https://turkiyedepremapi.herokuapp.com/api',{
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: Can you show surrounded code? Where is `deprem.js` line 11?

Comment: the first .then @Justinas

Comment: The response value is an empty string or otherwise invalid JSON.

Comment: how am i gonna figure that out if it is empty or invalid?

Comment: sounds like the response you're receiving is not a json.

Comment: i am fetching data from this url 'https://turkiyedepremapi.herokuapp.com/api' , it is json as far as i can understand, isn't it ?

Comment: @fatihthebach your browser has a "Network" developer tool that can show you exactly what was returned from the server.

Comment: Using "no-cors" means you are going to get a null body so `response.json()` will always error.

Comment: @Pointy i don't know how to confirm that i mean i never used that section of the browser, how can i understand the returned value from there?

Comment: @dwmorrin when i don't use it , i get this error 'Access to fetch at 'https://turkiyedepremapi.herokuapp.com/api' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.  TypeError: Failed to fetch'

Comment: "Opaque response" means the body will be null.  Do you control the API?  You need to allow CORS. https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque

Comment: i've added this code to allow it but it didn't work out, is it incorrect? ```var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(corsAttr);```

Answer (score 0):

`UnexpectedEndOfInput` means that you have not finished inputting data, when there is a new line or semicolon. Take all new lines out and try again. If that does not work, try looking for extra parentheses or brackets. If that does not work, you must check your line number eleven in the file, as this does not look like a full file, so there is likely code before it, which is creating the error.